# OSGi Remote Services : Riena + Declarative Services

Tags: osgi, remote-server

I have being following [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena/Getting_started_with_Remote_Services) tutorial on Riena Remote Services. Is there a project or tutorial available so I can use Riena along with Declarative Services? I'm finding a bit of a challenge converting the above example into Declarative Services.

Comment: You may have better luck asking specific technical questions. When you say you are *"finding it a bit of a challenge"* to convert the example, then you should describe which parts exactly are not clear to you - this might elicit more responses. Also, you should accept some answers, as this generally makes people more inclined to help you.